# Is it possible to download draw.io to my computer?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to download the draw.io app to my computer via their web UI?

I need it for my exam and have no internet access - and I haven't found any drawing program that fits my needs like this superb program

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is called "Draw.io Desktop". I have not tried it myself. I just found it as the second hit when I Googled "draw.io download".

Comment: Its a good tool. i am using it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The web app can be used offline with the following link: https://www.draw.io/index.html?offline=1

There is also a Chrome App.

([support.draw.io](https://support.draw.io/questions/2949145/how-to-use-draw.io-offline))